# getting aditional &amp; value after ejs template complitaltion

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am using `ejs` to generate xml file. The data json file as below

```
_data = {
      "category": "Science &amp; Reiligion"
}
```

being used in `ejs` xml template as follows

```
<itunes:category text="<%= _data.category %>"/>
```

after compilation, value is getting interpolated to `Science &amp;&amp;  Reiligion`.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%=` is to generate escaped content, so you need to use `<%-`

Change your code to the following

```
<itunes:category text="<%- _data.category %>"/>
```